# Given an unfilled pmf, How to compute the Correlation coefficient?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, correlation, covariance

This is the format in which I was given the PMF.

Given this pmf

$$\begin{array}{lll}
x&y&f_{xy}(x,y)\\
\hline
1&1&.25\\
1&2&.25\\
2&1&.25\\
0&0&.25
\end{array}$$

How to find the Correlation coefficient? I thought about making the formula

$$\frac{1}{4}\text{ from intervals }0\leq x \leq 2, 0\leq y \leq 2$$

But it makes less and less sense as i move on since i don't even have all the values for the pmf. Any help?

Comment: You have all the values. The given ones add up to $1$ so all other entries are $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so am i right in saying that the join pdf is 1/4 on intervals 0 < x < 2 and 0 <y < 2?

Comment: There is no **density** function, the distribution is discrete. Please see the answer for a detailed beginning to the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution is discrete. Since the given probabilities add up to $1$, the "missing" entries are all $0$, so are not missing at all.

To compute the correlation coefficient, you will need the covariance and the two variances. Let us start. From the table, $E(XY)=(1)(1)(0.25)+(1)(2)(0.25)+(2)(1)(0.25)+(0)(0)(0.25)$.

Now let us compute $E(X)$. This can be done directly from the table, but you might prefer to first find the pmf of $X$. From the table, we have $\Pr(X=1)=0.25+0.25=0.5$, $\Pr(X=2)=0.25$, and $\Pr(X=0)=0.25$. From this you can find that $E(X)=(1)(0.5)+(2)(0.25)+(0)(0.25)=1$.  Calculation of $E(X^2)$ is also straightforward.

When we look at $Y$, we get a pleasant surprise. Now it is a matter of putting the pieces together.

Comment: thankyou I got the answer $\frac{1}{2}$. I may have made some calculation errors but I now got the idea! :D

Comment: You are welcome. I also get $1/2$ for the correlation coefficient.